# Backbone.js + Handlebars each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to convert Ryan's [RailsCast on Backbone.js](http://railscasts.com/episodes/323-backbone-on-rails-part-1) to work with Handlebars and am stuck on a simple problem.

I can't seem to be able to iterate through a JSON array and display the result. I'm using these gems in my Gemfile

```
gem 'backbone-on-rails'
gem 'handlebars_assets'
```

In my `index.jst.hbs`, I have the following:

```
{{entries.length}}

<ul>
    {{#each entries.models}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

The API call seems to be working, as you can see in the count of 7 in the screenshot.
[image]

However, the content of each model isn't being displayed. Here's the View (index.js.coffee) and JSON response below.

```
 class Raffler.Views.EntriesIndex extends Backbone.View
      template: JST['entries/index']

      initialize: ->
        #triggered when view gets created, listen to 'reset' event, then re-@render, pass 'this' for context binding
        @collection.on('reset', @render, this)

      render: ->
        $(@el).html(@template(entries: @collection))
        this
```

JSON:

```
[
{
"created_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"id":1,
"name":"Matz",
"updated_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"winner":null
},
{
"created_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"id":2,
"name":"Yehuda Katz",
"updated_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"winner":null
},
{
"created_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"id":3,
"name":"DHH",
"updated_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"winner":null
},
{
"created_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"id":4,
"name":"Jose Valim",
"updated_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:28Z",
"winner":null
},
{
"created_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:29Z",
"id":5,
"name":"Dr Nic",
"updated_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:29Z",
"winner":null
},
{
"created_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:29Z",
"id":6,
"name":"John Nunemaker",
"updated_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:29Z",
"winner":null
},
{
"created_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:29Z",
"id":7,
"name":"Aaron Patterson",
"updated_at":"2012-06-28T18:54:29Z",
"winner":null
}
]
```

Answer (score 11):

Your `@collection` is, presumably, a `Backbone.Collection`. Handlebars will see it as an array of some sort so `{{entries.length}}` works as expected and `{{#each entries.models}}` iterates the right number of times; however, Handlebars has no idea what to do with the `Backbone.Model`s that are inside `@collection.models`.

Convert the `@collection` to raw data using [`toJSON`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON), Handlebars knows what to do with simple JavaScript arrays and objects:

```
render: ->
    @$el.html(@template(entries: @collection.toJSON()))
    @
```

And then adjust your template to look at just `entries` rather than `entries.models`:

```
<ul>
    {{#each entries}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tKna3/

A general rule with Backbone is to pass `model.toJSON()` or `collection.toJSON()` to your templates so that they don't have to know about Backbone methods (such as `get`) and so that your templates don't accidentally alter your models and collections.